# Firebase security rules not works

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am using Firebase Authentification in an Web application, and I am using Phone Number authentification as an option to sign in the application.

```
function saveUser(fname) {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var newUserRef = firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid);
    newUserRef.set({
        fname: fname
    });
}
```

Under the following database rules:

```
{
  "rules" : {
    ".read"  : false,
    ".write" : false,
    // only authenticated users can write
    "users": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      "$user_id": {
          "fname": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": "auth != null",
            ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().matches(/^[A-Z]{3,}$/)"
          },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I keep getting the error:

> FIREBASE WARNING: set at /users/ypGXpJRM1wdMOuOMf8F7quLnJ073 failed:
>   permission_denied

Is there a way to avoid this error without changing the rules?

Comment: Have you tested these rules in the simulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first level where your rules allow writing is in `/users/$uid/fname`. But your code tries to write to `/users/$uid`. Since you don't have write permission there, the database rejects the write operation.

You have two options to solve this: allow writes to `/users/$uid`, or write to `/users/$uid/fname`.

#### Allow writes to `/users/$uid`

To allow writes to `/users/$uid` change your rules to:

```
"users": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  "$user_id": {
      ".write": "auth != null",
      "fname": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
```

In fact, you'll likely want to ensure a user can only write their own node, which you do with:

```
"users": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  "$user_id": {
      ".write": "auth.uid === $uid",
      "fname": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
```

#### Write to `/users/$uid/fname`

Your current write code tries to write to a place where you don't have permission. Since you are only writing the `fname`, you can also write to that specific location to get rid of the error:

```
var newUserRef = firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid);
newUserRef.child('fname').set(fname);
```

Given the data structure I'd probably go for modifying the security rules.

Answer (score 0):

These rules are blocking all access:

```
".read"  : false,
".write" : false,
```

You can easily test your db security rules in Firebase database rule simulator tool.

Comment: I removed as recommended as well as I simulated. However, nothing changes.

Comment: I change ".write" : false, to ".write" : "auth != null" and works fine! thanks

Comment: Just a note to emphasize, read & write will override deeper rules if they're set in shallower layers. Only .Validate applied to the node that is being applied to without changing any thing deeper. Cheers

Comment: If you made that change on the root of your database, any authenticated user can now write to the entire database. While that is convenient, it is likely not the security model you want (given what you started with).